# Getting rid of if-cases

Tags: c#

I have an array that I need to build into a string. That is, if I have an array of { "a2", "a17", "a873" } it'll producre "a2, a17, a873". I reached that end goal but I'm not entirely happy about my code - in fact, I think it's kinda ugly but I'm also not able to come up with a better solution. Anyone?

```
for (var i = 0; i < actualSetpointCount; i++)
            {
                //If the first is also the last
                if (i == 0 && i == actualSetpointCount - 1)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append('\"' + arrayDataSet[i] + '\"');
                }
                //If first
                else if (i == 0)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append('\"' + arrayDataSet[i]);
                    stringBuilder.Append(',');

                }
                //If last setpoint
                else if (i == actualSetpointCount - 1)

                {
                    //If the last one doesnt have a qutationmark
                    if (!arrayDataSet[i][arrayDataSet[i].Length - 1].Equals('\"'))
                        stringBuilder.Append(arrayDataSet[i] + "\"");
                    else
                        stringBuilder.Append(arrayDataSet[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(arrayDataSet[i]);
                    stringBuilder.Append(',');
                }
            }
```

Comment: You would probably get a better answer to this question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: var arr = new []{ "a2", "a17", "a873" };
var str = string.Join(",", arr);

Comment: Have you tried to use Linq to search in the array for the values you want and then treat the result?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [string.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
string[] data = new string[] {"a2", "a17", "a873"};

string output = "\"" + string.Join(", ", data) + "\"";
```

If you only need the elements until a given index, you can use LINQ:

```
string output = "\"" + string.Join(", ", data.Take(actualSetpointCount)) + "\"";
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the initial array is around 500 long, populated with some default value. That's what my actualSetpointCount is for - that tells me how much of it is populated

Comment: You can use LINQ if you don't need all of the strings: `string output = string.Join(", ", data.Take(actualSetpointCount));` will only use the items of the array until `actualSetpointCount`

Comment: Okay, that's damn sexy. Appreciated man

Answer (score 0):

No *Linq*, `for` loop solution, just *one* `if`: should we add a delimiter:

```
   stringBuilder.Append('"'); // Quotation at the very beginning

   for (var i = 0; i < actualSetpointCount; i++) {
     if (i > 0)        // If we have items put
       sb.Append(","); // we should add a delimiter BEFORE the next item

     sb.Append(arrayDataSet[i]);
   }

   stringBuilder.Append('"'); // Quotation at the very end
```